# Not loading drivers for USB devices

Tags: drivers, upgrade, usb, 22.04

I just upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 and now ubuntu has decided that most USB drivers are overrated. It seems to only load HID and storage drivers, I can't get anything else to work.

I know all of these devices to work both with the previous installation of 20.04 as well as 22.04 on my laptop without any issues or additional setup (apart from the internal wireless card which I can't plug into the laptop).

Why does it not load the respective drivers here? Do I have to manually install drivers somehow? Is there some setting that would prevent it from loading these USB drivers?

Any tips are appreciated.

Here is my output of `lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 8, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

Edit: requested commands:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. G402 Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c33a Logitech, Inc. G413 Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13ba:0018 PCPlay Barcode PCP-BCG4209
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1b71:0056 Fushicai USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`:

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-42-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 if you want to have an accepted response: I installed `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` which failed due to missing `linux-headers-5.19.0-42-generic
` so I installed that and then reinstalled the extra modules and now usb drivers exist :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. Answer posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-42-generic' is not installed

It is likely that the 'extras' package is installed in an earlier kernel version and that the drivers are therefore working there. Please boot into an earlier kernel at the GRUB menu and then do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-42-generic
```

If this is not working, download the package here and transfer it on a USB key or similar. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-42-generic Install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

**CAUTION**: Please be certain that the package you install matches the running kernel where the drivers are not present. Find out:

```
uname -r
```

Comment: Can you add info why "boot into an earlier kernel" is needed? (to make this answer better for future reference....)